# How to store NSArray in NSDictionary with NSUserDefault

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

First of all I want to say that I am new in iOS. I am facing a problem. I've tried many things but have not achieved any success.
In my app I declared a `NSDictionay` in my `.pch` file like so:

```
#define Default_InCategory @{@[@"Other",@"other_icon.png"], @[@"Salary",@"salary_icon.png"]]}
```

These are some default values for a category. I also have an option from which the user can add custom values in this category. Due to some restrictions I am storing `New Custom` category in another separate key with name `Custom_InCategory` same as the above format. But I have not achieved any success. I am trying with the below code:

```
#define USERDEFAULT [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]

NSMutableDictionary *tempDic =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[USERDEFAULT objectForKey:Custom_InCategory]];

NSArray *tempArr =@[@"CategoryName",@"imageName"];

[tempDic setObject:tempArr forKey:@"newCat"];

[USERDEFAULT setObject:tempDic Custom_InCategory];
[USERDEFAULT synchronize];
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error,But I am not able to produce same format as at top of my exmaple

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to store single key-value paired dictionary then we can directly store in UserDefaults.

If your dictionary is collection of dictionaries then it will throw an error while storing.

For that situation, you need to Archive your Dictionary into data and then store it to UserDefaults. When you need the dictionary, then Unarchive the data back to Dictionary as following :

**Archive Dictionary to Data :**

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourDictionary];
```

**Store this Data to UserDefaults as following :**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:data forKey:@"yourData"];
```

**Get the Data from UserDefaults :**

```
NSData *archivedData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"yourData"];
```

**Unarchive Dictionary from Data :**

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedData];
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine:

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSArray *tempArr =@[@"CategoryName",@"imageName"];

[tempDic setObject:tempArr forKey:@"newCat"];

NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[myDefaults setObject:tempDic forKey:@"myKey"];

NSLog(@"%@",[myDefaults objectForKey:@"myKey"]);
```

In the console it prints:

```
{
newCat =     (
    CategoryName,
    imageName
);
}
```

**Update as per comment :**

You should use Different key to store different objects like, `newCat, newCat1, newCat2` etc or you can use `mutablearray` instead of dictionary and can add multiple object and retrieve it by it's index.

Comment: it is good for first time but at second time it will replace first newCat values with new one. And i want to store category as my first example (On Top)

Comment: then you should use array instead of dicrtionary. because if you calling `[tempDic setObject:tempArr forKey:@"newCat"];` this sentance it means you are setting object for `newCat` key so if there exists any object then it will replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:

Save an array of Dictionary in UserDefaults

```
func save(arr: NSArray) {
    guard let data = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: arr , requiringSecureCoding: false) as Data
    else { fatalError("Can't encode data") }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "ReferredBy")
}
```

Get an array of Dictionary from UserDefaults

```
func get() -> NSArray {

    if let unarchivedObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "ReferredBy") as? Data {
        guard let nsArray = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(unarchivedObject) as! NSArray else {
            return NSArray()
        }
        return nsArray            
    }
    return NSArray()
}
```